# Light bulbs flashing on when disconnected

Tags: energy, visible-light, electricity

For the 2nd time I've had a lightbulb flash on in my hand after removing from the power socket.  The first time the overhead light in my hallway was out for a couple of days before I got around to changing it.  This was a cfl bulb and after I unscrewed it and was making my way down the ladder it flashed back on in my hand for about 3 seconds and went back out.  I decided to put it back in the fixture and it went back to working.  It's now approximately 4 months later and again the bulb went out.  I unscrewed from the socket, had the tube end in my hand coming down the ladder when it again flashed on briefly and went back out.  I tried putting it back in the fixture and again it has gone back to working.  I don't know what to make of this as I've been unable to find any explanation as to how this can happen.  What could make a disconnected bulb light up in my hand without any power source? Any thoughts?

Comment: CFLs have electronic circuits with capacitors that can hold charge for a while in the white socket part of the bulb. In http://www.pavouk.org/hw/lamp/isotronic11w.png you can see that capacitor C4 may hold up to approx. 0.1J in energy, which would be enough to cause a few short flashes.

Comment: This happened to me as well,in my hallway too! I was replacing it because it had gone out. Instead, I screwed it back into the socket and asked my brother to turn the light switch on. Then I removed the bulb again and we watched it flash in my hand again! I've never before had experienced this phenomenom. I then attempted to use my powers of concentration to effect another flash while still holding the bulb, but of course that didn't work. So I don't know the answer, but glad to know this happened to others.

Comment: That's just like my own experience. Contrary to the replies that suggested this could be a case of static electricity I can attest there was no static whatsoever. My home has a good balance of humidity to dryness and I've never had a problem with static electricity build up anywhere. I think I would have felt an electric shock like one does when you have static on you. Chalk it up to weird unexplained phenomena, possibly paranormal

Answer (score 1):

Flurescent light bulbs are known for the way they light up when subjected to static electricity. [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNYpxc6stMo) of an instructor using a Van de Graaff generator to light up an old fashioned fluorescent light. CFLs are just old fashioned fluorescent bulbs bent into a different shape with a DC power supply tacked on.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is a loose internal connection.

Most CFL circuits have two functional parts. A set of diodes rectify mains to charge a capacitor to a few hundred volts DC. An inverter in the base turns that DC into high frequency AC to light the tube.

A loose connection in the inverter means when you turn on the lamp, the diodes charge the capacitor, but the inverter draws no power. The capacitor could hold a charge for hours after being switched off.

Moving the bulb around allows the loose part to complete the circut, starting the inverter and lighting the tube for a moment until the capacitor runs out of energy.

With the part roughly back in place, the bulb works for a while until it again falls out of place.

Source: opening some failed CFLs. The failure cause was often poor soldering.